# PHP "standalone" CMS

Tags: php, cms

I am looking for a CMS that I can incorporate in to any existing PHP website. So let's say for example I have an e-commerce website in Laravel. Suppose the client wants the ability to update the homepage banners and the FAQs page, about us, terms and conditions, etc.

Now of course I can build a custom CMS for the client, but this would be too tedious. I want something like a Composer package that can be installed and provides a CMS capability. I'm not bothered if the data is stored in the DB or in files.

So far I have not been able to find anything. The closest I have come is a headless CMS like [Directus](https://directus.io/) but this doesn't really work on the basis of "pages". It's more like collections of items.

Basically I need something like WordPress but on a smaller scale. I want the CMS to be part of the application - I don't want my application to be built within the CMS.

The CMS should allow me to create different content types and fields, so for example the "about us" page would have different fields to the "contact us" page.

Ideally open source but don't mind paying.

Comment: Take a look at http://www.cmsmatrix.org/ It has a wizard which should help you to choose.